# Make a query from a pure php to query CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've learned CodeIgniter, but I had difficulty in the conversion of pure php query to query CodeIgniter, how to fix my query in CodeIgniter?

This query using Codeigniter

```
public function get_kal($id) {
    $query = $this->db
            ->select('myname as name')
            ->from('mytable')
            ->where('myname', $id)
            ->like('%%%s%%')
            ->order_by('myname','ASC');
            ->get("q");

    $arr = array();

    $rs = mysql_query($query);

    while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs))
    {
        $arr[] = $obj;
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);     
}
```

This query with pure php

```
public function get_name($id) { 
        $query = sprintf("SELECT  myname as name from mytable WHERE myname LIKE '%%%s%%' ORDER BY myname DESC ", mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["q"]));
        $arr = array();
        $rs = mysql_query($query);

        while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs))
        {
            $arr[] = $obj;
        }

        echo json_encode($arr); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can Directly query by using

```
$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

you can also build query

```
$query = $this->db
            ->select('myname as name')
            ->from('mytable')
            ->like('myname', $this->input->get('q', TRUE))
            ->order_by('myname','ASC');
```

Here is the [Official Doc](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#select)

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query($SQL);
echo json_encode($query->result_array());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use by below format also.
1. Multiple Results
2. Single Result

```
1. $q = $this->db->query('MYSQL QUERY');
echo json_encode($q->result_array());


2.$q = $this->db->query('MYSQL QUERY');
echo json_encode($q->row_array());
```